# JavaScript Dynamic Diagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, raphael, jointjs

Quick question, I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and I will undoubtedly learn a lot from this project. So I propose a question (which could well be a silly one), my question is:

I am planning to build a web application that dynamically generates shapes from either Raphael or Joint.js both of which are very similar, by dynamic I mean that there will be an undefined amount of objects to draw until the user enters, for example the amount of objects they wish to draw - so here's some code to reinforce my question:

```
var erd = Joint.dia.erd;
Joint.paper("world", 800, 250);

var e1 = erd.Entity.create({
    rect: {
        x: 220,
        y: 70,
        width: 100,
        height: 60
    },
    label: "Entity"
});
```

So, I've created a object of type rectangle, but here is what I want to know - can I do this:

```
var erd = Joint.dia.erd;
Joint.paper("world", 800, 250);
int x, y;
for (int i = 0; i < numOfUserDefObjects; i++) {
    var e1 = erd.Entity.create({
        rect: {
            x: x,
            y: y,
            width: 100,
            height: 60
        },
        label: "Entity"
        x + 20;
        y - 40;
    });
}
```

All is what puzzles me is, the `var e1`. If there are 2 objects to be created, will the first object created in the loop be erased/deleted/overwritten from my SVG/Canvas whenever the loop iterates through the loop for a second time/to create the second object?

A little insight to this would be greatly appreciated! Again, lack JavaScript experience but that'll change.

Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, local variables declared with `var` have function scope.  That means there is exactly one copy of that local variable per function.  So, in your second code block, there is only one copy of the variable `e1` and the `for` loop is assigning different values to it in every iteration.

You can do what you are doing, but `e1` will only have one value in it when you're done and that value will be whatever the last iteration of the `for` loop assigned to it.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you could create an array of your objects like this:

```
var erd = Joint.dia.erd;
Joint.paper("world", 800, 250);
var x = 0, y = 0;
var objs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numOfUserDefObjects; i++) {
    objs.push(erd.Entity.create({
        rect: {
            x: x,
            y: y,
            width: 100,
            height: 60
        },
        label: "Entity"
    }));
    x += 20;
    y -= 40;
}
// objs now contains an array of the created objects
```

---

Note: I also initialized x and y, fixed the declarations to use `var` instead of `int` and correctly increment and decrement x and y in the `for` loop.  You had a lot of syntax errors in the code you posted.

Comment: Ah yes, I would of came across these when I came to build the application as of right now I'm planning my approach in my mind and wanted to pre-emptively ask this question so that it didn't trip me up in the near future, but thank you for the clear and concise answer.